# Android - PayPal payment "sendAuthorizationToServer"

Tags: android, paypal, authorization, payment

I'm trying to integrate PayPal on my app and to learn how PayPal SDK works I'm playing with the sample app. I know that after the user press "buy" button I need to send the authorization response to my server to verify the payment. The problem is that I couldn't find any example about how to do it. I've read the [official doc site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) but I don't understand how should I do it because I found very confuse information.

These are the different ways that I found:

[Verify a mobile payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI 
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
          -H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"
```

[Accept a PayPal payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y/execute/ 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}'
-d '{ "payer_id" : "7E7MGXCWTTKK2" }'
```

Which is the correct way to do it and what are the differences between both?

This is my real problem. The sample app has this fragment of code, where get the response from PayPal's servers, but I don't know how integrate the code above with the Java code.

```
    PaymentConfirmation confirm =  data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
   if (confirm != null) {
     try {          
        Toast.makeText(this,"Paymnet Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
        /**
        *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
        * or consent completion.
        * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
        * for more details.
        *
        * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
        * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
        */         
        Toast.makeText(
                 getApplicationContext(),
                 "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .show();

     } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
     }
 }
```

I have some experience with Android but this is the first time that I try to integrate one library like PayPal and I've never needed any kind of web service before.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, did you overcome this issue and found a solution for?

Answer (score 0):

@jgarciabt - You want to verify the payment that was created in your mobile app.  Here is an example implementation: https://github.com/avidas/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend

Comment: I read it before, but I've never worked with python before and I don't know if I can and how integrate this code on android.

Comment: A main point of payment verification is that is is performed from your servers and not from the mobile.